# Why does text-align center headers?

Tags: html, css, text-align

Why does text-align: center headers?
Headers are block elements h1,h2,etc. Why is it that text-align centers headers even though the documentation specifically says it does not: [Docs on text-align](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#alignment-prop)

> This property describes how inline-level content of a block container
>   is aligned.

I'm a little confused as to why it wont center a block element like a div, but willing to center a header. Could it potentially be because text inside a header is inline, but the actual header itself is a block element?

http://codepen.io/stephenhuh/pen/KrkLZG - codepen on this phenomenon.

```
* {
    text-align: center;
}

.box {
    background-color: blue; 
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: As you said, the header isn't centered; the text inside it is.

Comment: @smarx Is it fair to say then that all text is inline? I'm looking for documentation that says that headers are containers of text that are block and that text itself is inline but can't seem to find anything like that.

Comment: Your question contains the perfect answser: *This property describes how inline-level content of a block container is aligned.* The text is the inline-level content of the block container, whether it be an `h1`, `p`, `article`, `section`, `div`, etc. Look into anonymous inline boxes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [CSS 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes):

> Any text that is directly contained inside a block container element (not inside an inline element) must be treated as an anonymous inline element.

Comment: Your link, in addition to, [docs on DOM nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) cleared it up for me. As Node.ELEMENT_NODE is differentiated from Node.TEXT_NODE, it makes sense that two are treated differently.

Comment: `<p>` elements are `display: block` by default. Then and now.

Answer (score 2):

Like everyone else has already explained, it is centering the text content inside the header element. I'd just like to add that you can easily test this by adding a border or background to elements. If you do this, you'll notice that the header will span the entire width of its container by being a block element, and the text will only be centered inside that block.

(Alternatively, you could use an inspector to show the actual space an element is occupying)

Answer (score 0):

The property `text-align` affects specific children of the parent that the property was assigned; namely inline type children. Text is inline, as well as spans and inputs unless otherwise overridden by CSS.  If you need to center a block level element (horizontally) use `margin:0 auto;`.